# Generating event when user clicks in textarea with disabled=true, to tell them they can't modify it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to tell the user they can't modify a textarea that's been disabled for update, when they try to click in it.  How can I tell them why it is disabled in this case, e.g. with an alert?

The problem is/was, when I give the textarea a disabled attribute, the events for it don't fire off either (at least in Chrome).

Comment: Yes, you can use alert to do that. Seriously, what is the question? What did you try to do and how it didn't work? Did you try handling the click event?

Comment: When I added an alert in a clickevent, it popped it up, but then still lets the user edit the field.  If I made it disabled, then the clickevent was disabled too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing your main concern is that the `disabled`attribute doesn't allow events on IE.

The `readonly`attribute, however, does:

```
<texarea readonly onclick="alert('Please do not edit me!');">
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that attribute.  ... And I hope the disabled attribute works the same in all browsers, blocking events, not just IE! ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the onclick property in the textarea tag. You could do it something like this:

```
<textarea onclick="alert('CAN'T TOUCH THIS!')">
    blahblahblahblahblahblahblah
</textarea>
```

Here's another example:

```
<textarea onclick="textareaclicked();">
    blahblahblahblahblahblahblah
</textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function textareaclicked() {
        alert("CAN'T TOUCH THIS!");
    }
</script>
```

One final example:

```
<textarea onclick="textareaclicked('Someone set up us the bomb :(');">
    blahblahblahblahblahblahblah
</textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function textareaclicked(var s) {
        alert(s);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should only use a `disabled` html attribute and do some stylish to disabled elements like a gray color:

```
<style>
  .disabled {
    background-color:gray;
  }
</style>

<textarea disabled="disabled" class="disabled" title="Disable for update"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say wrap it in a span and give that the event. (note to all, it doesn't allow a click event on a disabled textarea in chrome).

http://jsfiddle.net/yU7ku/

HTML

```
<textarea disabled></textarea>
```

jQuery

```
$("[disabled]")
    .wrap("<span></span>")
    .parent()
    .click(function(){
        alert("this "+this.firstChild.nodeName+" is disabled");
    });
```